# PGDLLIMPORT and PostgreSQL C hooks

Tags: c, postgresql, winapi

I've been using PostgreSQL hooks for some time now, and yesterday I wanted to try to add my own hook to test something(and for fun).

So I looked up `ExecutorStart_hook` to see what are the things I would need to do in order to get my own hook into PostgreSQL.

In *execMain.c* it is pretty straight forward, first define the hook

```
ExecutorStart_hook_type ExecutorStart_hook = NULL;
```

then use it in `ExecutorStart(...);`.

In *executor.h* we define the hook type first, and then we **import** the hook variable.

```
typedef void (*ExecutorStart_hook_type) (QueryDesc *queryDesc, int eflags);
extern PGDLLIMPORT ExecutorStart_hook_type ExecutorStart_hook;
```

Where are importing this hook variable from? I don't see it anywhere else except in *execMain.c*, and I don't see a `PGDLLEXPORT` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On non-windows platforms, that does nothing.

On windows, `PGDLLIMPORT`'s meaning changes based on whether the PostgreSQL server is being compiled, or an extension. The headers are written from the perspective of an extension, which is why it says `PGDLLIMPORT`.

If you look at the definition of `PGDLLIMPORT` in `src/include/port/win32.h`:

```c
#ifdef BUILDING_DLL
#define PGDLLIMPORT __declspec (dllexport)
#else                           /* not BUILDING_DLL */
#define PGDLLIMPORT __declspec (dllimport)
#endif
```

... you'll see that if `BUILDING_DLL` is set, we expand it to `__declspec(ddlexport)`. So it *exports* the symbol from the server binary. We only set `BUILDING_DLL` when compiling `postgres.exe`; its name a bit unfortunate. It's like that because on Windows you're usually exporting symbols from DLLs for use in applications, not vice versa like in postgres.

If `BUILDING_DLL` is not set, we define `PGDLLIMPORT` to `__declspec(dllimport)`, importing the symbol from the server binary into whatever's linking to it.

So ... when postgres includes `executor.h` it *exports* the symbol. When you include `executor.h` in your extension DLL project, it *imports* the symbol.

All this is necessary because of [how DLL linkage works on win32/PE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx). On ELF platforms (Linux, BSD, etc) and Mach-O (Mac OS X), none of it is necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This makes a lot more sense now.